# Dynamically search in a generic list

Tags: c#, list, search

I am trying to create a function to dynamically search in a generic list in C#.

I created a function that uses reflection.

```
List<T> Search<T>(List<T> lst, string propertyName, string value)
{
    var searchedList = (from item in lst
                        where item.GetType()
                                  .GetProperty(propertyName)
                                  .GetValue(item)
                                  .ToString() == value
                        select item)
                       .ToList();
}
```

In addition, I was trying to invoke the FindALL method on the list using reflection with no luck. Does anybody have any idea how to perform this functionality.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do this with property names? How is this method used? What does "no luck" translate into in real terms?

Comment: This method will be called several times, each time with different property name and value

Comment: Am I to understand that the property name isn't known at compile time?

Comment: Yes this correct. the property name is not know at compile time.

Comment: Can you advise what went wrong with the current attempt? Can you provide a full failing example? Are there any successful examples?

Comment: `no luck` is not a technical description of a problem

Comment: Nothing went wrong, it is working. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this functionality.

Comment: i dont know what **no luck** means but i think you should use `Equals()` instead of `ToString()` and return a single item from the function instead of the whole list

Comment: Show us short example with usage of this stuff

Comment: if it's _working code_ and you're just concerned about performance, it might be better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

I would move the reflection out of the loop and maybe have a comparer.

```
public IEnumerable<T> ReflectionSearch<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string propName, string value, StringComparer comparer = null)
{
    var t = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);
    if (t == null) throw new Exception("No such prop");
    comparer = comparer ?? StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var v = t.GetValue(item)?.ToString();

        if (comparer.Equals(v, value))
            yield return item;
    }
}
```